# automate operations within a Virtualbox machine

Tags: ubuntu, automation, virtual-machine, virtualbox, expect

I'm Having some trouble in a vm that seems to occur only once in a hundred during shutdown/reboot.
To help the debug, I'm thinking to write a script that runs on my desktop, which starts the vm and automate operations for a huge number of times (keyboard key pressed) whithin it. (VirtualBox preferred).
It's just exactly how a script using the expect lib would do with a program in command line.

I'm not sure it's possible, but anyway, if anyone has an idea...

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The VirtualBox help file (installed with VirtualBox) has a very detailed Command Reference section. Check it out. I have used the VBoxManage command to start VMs via command line. There are several other commands and command options. For automating commands inside the VM, you can use a batch file or a shell script and make it part of the startup commands.